# Unmounting a react-native app inside an existing app

Tags: react-native

In our app iteration, the parent app was controlling a navbar, and the react-native app was mounted below it.  We had a few layout issues that `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets` was unable to fix, plus we were having consistency issues between iOS and Android.

To solve these issues, we wanted to move the navbar into react, but this leaves us with another problem; how can we send a message from javascript up to our native container (ie a navigator) that an event has occured (ie we are ready to tear down the react app).